# android json (output string and array) parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

how can parsing this output

```
{
    "durum": "tamam",
    "mahalleler": [
        {
            "mahalle_kodu": "1",
            "mahalle_ismi": "BEKTAŞ MAH."
        },
        {
            "mahalle_kodu": "2",
            "mahalle_ismi": "ÇARŞI MAH."
        }]}
```

i try this code but return "null".

```
            contacts = json.getJSONArray("mahalleler");

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = c.getString("mahalle_kodu");
                String body = c.getString("mahalle_ismi");}
```

what is the problem? json output has two variable; mahalleler[] and durum. i wanna parse durum's valur and values of mahalleler array. But i couldnt do that.

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Where are you trying to output the data? Defining your variables in your `for loop` makes them local to that loop. Try creating `class variables` and assigning them value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hve to do get json array like this

```
JSONArray mahallelerArray = c.getJSONArray("mahalleler");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{
"durum": "tamam",
"mahalleler": [
    {
        "mahalle_kodu": "1",
        "mahalle_ismi": "BEKTAŞ MAH."
    },
    {
        "mahalle_kodu": "2",
        "mahalle_ismi": "ÇARŞI MAH."
    }]}
   ");

 String name[]
    String body[]

      JSONArray  contacts = json.getJSONArray("mahalleler");
         name=new String[contacts.length()];
      body  =new String[contacts.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

             name[i] = c.getString("mahalle_kodu");
             body[i] = c.getString("mahalle_ismi");}
```

i think u r nt geting o/p as u declared the strings inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if the content is in the json:

```
if (json != null && !json.isNull("mahalleler")) {
   JSONArray contacts = json.getJSONArray("mahalleler");

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = c.getString("mahalle_kodu");
            String body = c.getString("mahalle_ismi");}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your `String` inside your `for loop`. Make them class variables arrays to store the data.